# update sharepoint list from webpart using toggle

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-ui-fabric

I'm using Sharepoint Online and have a UI Office Fabric Toggle in my webpart like this with the event to handle changes.

```
<Toggle label="Enabled and checked" defaultChecked onText="On" offText="Off" onChange={_onChange} />

private _onChange (ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, checked: boolean) {
    console.log('toggle is ' + (checked ? 'checked' : 'not checked'));
    this.setState(dpiPOSApprover:checked)
}
```

What code do I put in my submit event to update the corresponding yes / no field in my Sharepoint list to reflect the Yes or No selected in the Toggle?

At the moment I have something like this.

```js
let ToggleValue=this.state.ToggleValue;
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("FinanceSystemAccessRequestForm").items.add({
    Title:  this.state.dpselectedItem.key,
    ListColumn:ToggleValue,

}).then(i => { console.log(i); });
```

Comment: Could you provide the error that the request is returning  or generally more information regarding this issue? Because the code snippets look like they should be working correctly.

Comment: I had not added the method to constructor in React.  Just found this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not added the method to constructor in React. Just found this out.